# Add Custom Configuration Source to ASP.NET Core during Startup.Configure

Tags: asp.net-core

While Microsoft provides an example of adding a custom configuration source in [ConfigureAppConfiguration](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/configuration/index/samples/3.x/ConfigurationSample/Program.cs), that is too early for what I need to do, as I need DI to add services before I am ready or even know if I have custom providers to register. Is there anyway I can add to the configuration sources/providers during `Startup.Configure`? I'm fine this source is only available in subsequent requests after application startup.

In an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project, I've tried injecting `IConfigurationRoot` but I cannot find a way to add to the `Providers` enumerable. Any help you can offer would be great.

Here is some pseudo-pseudo code demonstrating what I would like to do in an ideal/fool's world:

```
public class Startup
{     
    private IConfigurationRoot ConfigurtionRoot;

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonSettings(env.ContentRootPath, env.EnvironmentName)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        ConfigurationRoot = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServicesCollection services)
    {
       services.AddServicesNeededForCustomConfigProvider();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
       var provider = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ICustomConfigProvider>();
       // This is where we need some magic to add providers/sources after the initial configuration is built.
       ConfigurationRoot.AddProvider(provider);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code of what you are referring to.

Comment: Added pseudo-pseudo code.